# How can i apply css stylesheet to single specific element?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development, I have tried css stylesheet with simple HTML element and it worked well, when i specified element name:

```
label {
    color: green;
}
```

this would be applied to all label tags, but is there any way to apply stylesheet to single element? For example: There are 2 labels, one is green and second is blue, How can this be achieved?

Comment: That is what classes and id's are for. http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/

Comment: That's just a learner's question. Why to downvote? What is missing in the question? Be kind stackoverflow!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen This is an _extremely basic_ learner's question; the fact the OP is asking it suggests they haven't read even an intro to the technology. Downvoting is not unkind, and should not be taken personally. It merely means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Sorry but I will never understand this point of view. Sometimes you will start learning a new topic and don't know the exact keywords to search for on google. And even though after weeks no matter how many tutorial materials you've finished, you sometimes can't target right keywords to search for. You would understand this more easily if English is not your mother tongue. That's one of the reasons that holding me back from asking questions on stackoverflow. Even that might be a question never asked before.

Comment: Maybe in the future, someone will start fresh learning css and will search exact same things as in title. Seach engines will guide him to this thread and that person will save lots of time.

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen I agree with you. Too many on this site beeing triggerhappy on the downvote. It's as if you should know everything **before** you ask a question here sometimes. Just recently I saw a guy get serious downvotes because he did not know what json was. How on earth is he supposed to google that? I too find this site not suitable to ask questions sometimes. I have asked several questions on other friedlier sites instead of here because of the attitude on this site.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I did have a research, but whatever i tried did not work because it was too specific in details, and i just couldn't understand the purpose as beginner.

Comment: I can confirm that on February 8, 2024 (almost a full decade later), this page is the third result for the Google query ``css+selector+single+element``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's lots of ways to accomplish this. There's lots of css selectors like ID, classes... See [css selectors reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Best way to achieve what you want is to use classss. See [classes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)

```css
.red {
      color: red;
}
.blue {
      color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label class="blue">
    I'm blue
</label>
<label class="red">
  I'm red
</label>
```

Comment: Class idea is very good! i used for loop on id, Thank's for awesome solutions.

Comment: You should also look for where to use ID's and where to use classes too. w3schools is a good start to learn things. I'd strongly recommend you to take [this course on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). It'll become more clear.

Comment: I am just beginner at Django though, i just use css and html for design and actions.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
    <label name="green">
    label[name=green]{
        color:green;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use id of the element if you want to target a specific element. Example:

```
#labelId{
    color: green;
}

<label id="labelId">Some Text</label>
```

Alternatively, you can also provide specific class name to the element. Example:

```
.label-class{
    color: green;
}

<label class="label-class">Some Text</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! class idea would be better, since i use for loop on id.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using html attributes such:

- `class`, `id`, `data-nameOFData` for any of HTML element

```css
.class {
  color: blue
}

#id {
  color: green
}

div[data-test] {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="class">class</div>
<div id="id">id</div>
<div data-test>data</div>
```

- `name` , `type` and `for` for `input` elements

```css
label[for="textInput"] {
  color: aqua
}

input[type="text"] {
  color: brown
}
```

```html
<label for="textInput">label</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="textInput" value="name" />
```

- `href` for anchors tags and `src` for images

```css
a {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: deepskyblue
}

a[href*="google"] {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">youtube</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

---

Also you can select any element without defining any attribute for it if you know his index using CSS pseudo selectors `:first-child` , `:nth-child(n)` ,  `:last-child` , `:first-of-type` , `:nth-of-type(n)` , `:last-of-type` , `:nth-of-type(even)`, `:nth-child(odd)`  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) , [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

div:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: coral
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```